Leading others to suicide
Imagine a situation where you are rude with someone, either during an argument or not, and this person is under severe mental distress and later they end up taking their own life.
What are the implications of this situation? Is this treated like an accidental murder?
What if a large number of people ridiculed or criticized someone, and that person took their own life afterwards because of the backlash, do all of the people involved become liable to some extent? Like in a case of bullying or public backlash.

On ethical grounds, the very act of shaming someone is likened to murder. If you're asking whether there are halachic implications to pushing someone to suicide, I don't think so.

Welcome to MiYodeya Fillipe and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Welcome, we divide between Halachic and ethical implications. For example, it is ethically bad to steal but the legal implication is payback, not lashes. Similarly, indirect psychological harm is not legally liable but is an ethical transgression of Hona'ah, see https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.58b.6?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=en
